# Problems with maintaining a network connection using a ZTE datacard provided by Neotel

Tags: modem

I have a Neotel datacard/modem that uses cdma, when first plugged in it works fine but abruptly disconnects and won't connect until I restart the computer im not certain on the model name and a link can be found here http://connection.neotel.co.za/datacard does anyone have an idea what the solution may be?

Comment: Are you on 11.10?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!